# Java: Sorting multiple languages

Tags: sorting, collation, multiple-languages

I am using a Java application, and I have a requirement where I have to sort the app names from Android Store. As the app names are in different language, I don't have the specific locale on which I could sort the app name (Collation).
Is there a way where I could compare the app names of different languages and sort the same?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can use "localeCompare" for sorting
Javascript Ex.
cityList = cityList.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));